# Is there anything that can be done to enable SRI hash validation for the youtube iframe API (enabling CORS on the domain)?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

As the title states, wondering if there might be anyone willing to discuss enabling an SRI hash friendly implementation.  I understand that this API is meant to be a dynamic resource, always using the latest version of the code, but security is of utmost importance for this application.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Brian, this is probably too broad, so it is [off-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Can you narrow down your question to something more specific? You may be able to discuss this topic in some of the [StackOverflow chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: To be more to the point - this really an attempt to reach support for the iframe api (as indicated here https://developers.google.com/youtube/players/support).  Currently the domain has CORS disabled and resource loading is structured in such a way to make SRI hashing impossible/ineffective.  Perhaps a subject for conversation in a chat room with the right audience.